# Unable to make still photos the same length in a project in iMovie '11

Tags: macos, photos, imovie

I was so proficient with iMovie '11 -- made more than 200 short videos.  Now I'm with iMovie 10.0.6 which crashes a lot, and everything is different.  I tried to follow the directions above, but when I click on "Window" there is no "Show Adjustments Bar" for me to click on, so I'm lost.  Or just having a senior moment?

**What I want to do is make all the still photos in a project the same length to start, then make adjustments.**  I can't figure out how to do that.

I can highlight all the stills, but nothing more than that.  If I try to adjust one by itself by dragging the two-headed arrow to the left or right, then hit play, when it comes to that photo it stops dead.  The audio goes on and on but the picture is frozen.

If I try to adjust it back to the original length it was, it still stops dead on the photo.  The only way to keep the vertical line moving is to delete the offending photo.  That's not good.  I'm getting so frustrated I'm deleting perfectly good photos because I can't figure out what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use [this Training video](http://www.lynda.com/iMovie-tutorials/iMovie-1002-Essential-Training/159634-2.html) to learn how to use iMovie.

iMovie 10.0.2 Essential Training
with Garrick Chow

The intro is free so you can then decide if you want to pay for full training.

Comment: Isn't answering *and voting to close* a bit of a mixed message?